# Prove that $E[\log(\alpha X_t^2)] < 0 $ implies $\alpha < 3.5622$ with $X_t \sim N(0,1)$

Tags: distributions, stationarity, garch, probability-inequalities

I am trying to prove this statement:

If $X_t \sim N(0,1)$ then

$$E[\log(\alpha X_t^2)] < 0 \implies \alpha < 3.5622$$

which is a a necessary condition often found in textbooks for strict stationary of ARCH(1). How can I do that? I think I have to exploit Jensen's Inequality but maybe I am wrong, since I do not get conclusions by the use of it.

Comment: Have you tried deriving the pdf of $\log(X_t^2)$ ? As $X_t$ is standard normal, then $X_t^2\sim\chi_1^2$ and by applying the pdf transform formula you seem to get

$$p_{\log(X_t^2)}(y) \propto \exp(\dfrac{y}{2})\exp\left(-\dfrac{e^y}{2}\right)$$

But I might be wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The random variable $\alpha X_t^2   \sim  \textrm{Gamma} \left( \frac{1}{2} , 2 \alpha \right). $

The logarithm of this, sometimes called a log-gamma distribution, has a mean of $ \psi \left(\frac{1}{2} \right) +\ln \left(2 \alpha \right),$ where $\psi$ is the digamma function.

For argument $\frac{1}{2},$ the digamma function has value $-2 \ln \left( 2 \right) - \gamma,$ where $\gamma$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant, with approximate value of 0.577216

So, if the expectation is negative, we have $$ \psi \left(\frac{1}{2} \right) +\ln \left(2 \alpha \right) < 0,$$ giving

$$ \ln \left(2 \alpha \right) < 2 \ln \left( 2 \right) + \gamma,$$
$$  2 \alpha  < 4 e^{\gamma},$$
$$  \alpha  < 3.5622 $$